# variable value not being parsed to another form class c#

Tags: c#

when a user clicks a button a value is assigned to the variable 'choice' and i need to use that variable value in another form class but the variable value that is been stored isn't being parsed to the other form class

here is my code:
form 1:

```
public partial class Main : Form
{
   public string choice { get; set; }
   string d1 = "something";

    private void btnD1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        choice = d1;
        this.Hide();
        Form2 f = new Form2();
        f.Show();
    }
}
```

form 2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Main m = new Main();
        MessageBox.Show("You chose: " + m.choice + " before, now choose again!");
    }
}
```

i put a message box before the application goes to the next form and it shows "something" but when the message box comes up in the new form, it displays "You chose: before, now choose again!"
what is the error?
thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Show us the code on how you set `choice`. You should probably display your form first too.

Comment: When you do new Main() the old instance of form (in which you've probably set the choice) is gone. You need to pass the original context somehow or make the field static.

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar... i have no idea how but i made my variable static and its working now! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, as documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20stz12s(v=vs.110).aspx), the `Show` method of `MessageBox` returns an instance of `DialogResult`, which is the intended means of communicating the user's interaction to the caller.

Comment: I think he has more of a problem creating a new instance of his data class and then refering to the new instance instead of the original instance where he did set the value. Is difficult to say though without seeing more of his code.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. There is no problem with the message box. It is showing perectly but just the content is not as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Use static variable to store "Choice" variable data..
MessageBox.Show(STATICCLS.Choice)

Comment: You should not solve a local problem with a global solution